# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency with useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I am trying to Save to Local in React and my app is working, but I cannot deploy it because of this warning. The warning is:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'saveLocalTodos'.
> Either include it or remove the dependency array

And my code is:

```
// Run once when the app starts
  useEffect(() => {
    getLocalTodos();
  }, []);

  // useEffect
  useEffect(() => {
    // Function
    function filterHandler() {
      switch (status) {
        case `completed`:
          setFilteredTodos(todos.filter((todo) => todo.completed === true));
          break;
        case `uncompleted`:
          setFilteredTodos(todos.filter((todo) => todo.completed === false));
          break;
        default:
          setFilteredTodos(todos);
          break;
      }
    }
    filterHandler();
    saveLocalTodos();
  }, [todos, status]);

  // Save to Local
  const saveLocalTodos = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
  };
  const getLocalTodos = () => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("todos") === null) {
      localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify([]));
    } else {
      let todoLocal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`todos`));
      setTodos(todoLocal);
    }
  };
```

Comment: The issue is the `linter`, removing the `[]` dependency will make the error go away, like this:
```javascript
useEffect(() => getLocalTodos())
```

Comment: Please refer to the [useEffect docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for further reference :). Cheers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix missing dependency warning when using useEffect React Hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook)

Comment: I have tried it, but it did not solve the error. Still shows the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just include your dependency in the dependencies array of `React.useEffect` then.

You're using `saveLocalTodos` inside your `useEffect` but not defining it in the dependencies array. Normally, the rule of thumb is to include everything (functions, variables, state, props) which is used inside the `useEffect` to be in the dependencies array. Because your effect depends on them and should reinvoke itself once their value changes.

```
 const saveLocalTodos = React.useCallback(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
  }, [todos]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Function
    function filterHandler() {
      switch (status) {
        case `completed`:
          setFilteredTodos(todos.filter((todo) => todo.completed === true));
          break;
        case `uncompleted`:
          setFilteredTodos(todos.filter((todo) => todo.completed === false));
          break;
        default:
          setFilteredTodos(todos);
          break;
      }
    }
    filterHandler();
    saveLocalTodos();
  }, [todos, status, saveLocalTodos]);
```

Also, wrap your `saveLocalTodods` with `React.useCallback` because, in every re-render of your component, the function reference changes. Then your effect will be fired for no reason. Put `todos` in the dependencies array inside the `saveLocalTodos`. You want your function to change only when todos change. Otherwise, you will get stale todos.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've tried it and now I'm having an error: saveLocalTodos' was used before it was defined  ‍♀️

Comment: What do you think is the cause of the error now? It is literally written in your error message. 

Define your function before it is used. I've updated the code now. Check it.

Comment: OMG‍♀️ have been sitting up to 1 am trying to figure it out and now my brain is not functioning. Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to programming!

Comment: Haha yes, you can tell I'm a newbie!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because inside `useEffect` you're calling `getLocalTodos`, `saveLocalTodos` function which are defined outside of useEffect. Ideally inside useEffect dependency array you should define all the outer function, props variable etc. which are used inside `useEffect`. So whenever there is any changes in the dependency the effect will be triggered inside `useEffect`. When you are creating any function wrap that function inside `React.useCallback` and there you can pass dependency of that particular function , just like for your case `saveLocalTodos` is dependent on todos, so your function will only change when todos will change. In that way your function will change only when necessary.

```
      const filterHandler = React.useCallback(() => {
        switch (status) {
            case `completed`:
              setFilteredTodos(todos.filter((todo) => todo.completed === true));
              break;
            case `uncompleted`:
              setFilteredTodos(todos.filter((todo) => todo.completed === false));
              break;
            default:
              setFilteredTodos(todos);
              break;
          }
      }, [todos, status]);
      
      // Save to Local
      const saveLocalTodos = React.useCallback(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
      }, [todos]);
      
      const getLocalTodos = React.useCallback(() => {
        if (localStorage.getItem("todos") === null) {
          localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify([]));
        } else {
          let todoLocal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`todos`));
          setTodos(todoLocal);
        }
      },[]);

      useEffect(() => {
        filterHandler();
        saveLocalTodos();
        getLocalTodos();
      }, [getLocalTodos, filterHandler, saveLocalTodos]);
```